# How to filter a Google GA4 report to exclude a trailing portion of a path?

Tags: analytics

The GA4 version of Google Analytics has an "Add filter +" button that allows me to define an "Exclude" filter and then define a "Dimension" to be excluded.

The Dimension that seems likely for my use case are "Page path and screen class".  But choosing this Dimension only permits me to select complete individual page paths from a drop down list.

The page path I want to exclude is a portion of this example:

https://xxx/Home/Components/News/News/1229/262

This URL is generated by our CMS system.  There are very many content items with similar page paths, but with different endings.  I'd like to create a filter that excludes all page-paths that contain this portion of the path:

https://xxx/Home/Components/News/News/

I've searched for hours to try to find a way to do this with no luck.

The reason for doing this is that hundreds of News articles use the link above only differing in the appended numerical suffix (/1229/262/) in the URL. And they show in our analytics reports, cluttering the data among other pages and making it hard to view the least accessed pages in the report that are outside of the set of News articles.

Is there a way to filter a portion of a page path when there is no querystring in the URLs as in my example?

I tried creating a filter on page-paths but was required to scroll through hundreds of paths in the drop down and manually select all the page paths that match my selection criteria.  There are hundreds of pages in the drop down and it's impractical to traverse hundreds of pages and manually select the filtered paths.

I wish I could enter an exclude page-path with a wildcard or regex like: https://xxx/Home/Components/News/News/*

Answer (score 1):

Probably too late to the party but...

You should be able to filter these out using Regex filter. It will need to be a FULL, CASE-SENSITIVE regex expression: /Home/Components/News/News/.* (Excluding https://xxx as that's not part of page path)

Depending on GA4's mood of the day, that should work!

Answer (score 0):

GA4 is insufferably inflexible and has less of those easy filtering or advanced search options that Universal Analytics had. e.g. Starts with, ends with, matches regex etc.

I just do not know the answers to these many questions.